Highlighting lines containing fold-markers when fold is open
When Vim/Neovim is configured to use markers as foldmethod, it highlights the line containing the marker if the fold is closed. When the fold is opened, the lines containing the markers look the same as normal lines.
Is it possible to configure Vim/Neovim to highlight lines that contain fold-markers when the fold is open?
Example of the highlighting of opened and closed markers:
nvim --clean --cmd "set foldmethod=marker" vim-fold-marker.md


Using :match
I've tried using :match with
highlight OpenedFold guifg=Black guibg=DarkGray
match OpenedFold /^.*\({{{\|}}}\s*\)/

however, this only highlights the line up to the column containing the last character and not the whole width of the buffer.
Also, ideally it would fill in the part of the line after the marker with a symbol as well, like the lines of the closed markers are filled with ·.

Version: NVIM v0.10.0


What is your actual goal?

The problem with the :match approach is, it will only highlight the line content, so it cannot highlight anything after the physical line content has ended. The same is true for syntax highlighting.
The only way if you want to highlight complete lines is to use make use of signs (:h sign). With that you could do the following:
" Define a highlighting group, in this case let's just use Red
:hi default Red ctermbg=DarkRed guibg=Red
" define a unique ID
:let s:sign_id = 200
" Define a new sign
:sign define Red linehl=Red
" Now place the line where you want it
:exe ":sign place " .. s:sign_id .. " line=3 name=Red buffer=" .. bufnr('%')
" increment the sign_id
:let s:sign_id += 1

A few years ago I made a very simple plugin BackgroundColor, to highlight single lines, see an example here
However, please note, this will statically attach the sign to the line mentioned. They are not updated when you start moving lines around or changing the buffer. I have made another plugin DynamicSigns which attempts to update lines as they are changed in the buffer using so called sign expressions, which are similar to fold expressions. See an example here. However since those signs need to be evaluated often, this may cause a certain slow down.
Possibly nvim has additional ways to highlight lines, but I have no idea about Neovim.

Could you not also do this using textprops, and aren't those effectively dynamic?

but you cannot attach those to the end of the line? Or can you? Not sure, haven't played yet enough with text properties

I’m not sure, but I thought textprops could do something similar to after-eol virtual text, so I assumed they could simulate the highlight. Might be harder to get the highlight right, though.
